# In Excel, How do I count the number of blank cells until the next non-blank cell

Tags: excel, count, nonblank

I have a spreadsheet which resembles the below. Column A is my data and Column B is what I am trying to achieve

```
         A           B
   +-----------+-----------+
1  | Some text |   A1:A3   |
   +-----------+-----------+
2  |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
3  |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
4  | Some text |   A4:A8   |
   +-----------+-----------+
5  |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
6  |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
7  |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
8  |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
9  | Some text |   A9:A9   |
   +-----------+-----------+
10 | Some text |  A10:A10  |
   +-----------+-----------+
11 |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
12 |           |           |
   +-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see, Column A just contains empty and non-empty cells (all cells, including empty ones, actually contain a formula). In column B, I need to return a range starting at the current row and ending at the first non-empty row, but only if Column A of the current row is not blank. The returned result is to be used within another function. For example B1 could be COUNTBLANK(A1:A3), although the actual function is not COUNTBLANK, but a custom function

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Do you care to share the solution?

Comment: What have you already achieved?

Comment: Very little. I have been playing with OFFSET to return a range, it is just the variable height that I am having problems with. EG. in B1 i have OFFSET(A1,0,0,2,1)

Answer (score 2):

Please add a letter at the bottom of your "occupied" ColumnA then try, in B1 and copied down:

```
=IF(A1="","","A"&ROW()&":A"&ROW()+MATCH("*",A2:A100,0)-1)
```

*Alternative to account for restriction mentioned by OP*

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1="","","A"&ROW()&":A"&ROW()+MATCH("*",A2:A$1048576,0)-1),"A"&ROW()&":A"&ROW())
```

Comment: Thanks pnuts. However, i cannot add anything in Column A. It's content is dynamically driven. I have no idea how many rows will be occupied from one minute to the next

Comment: Thanks again pnuts. I appreciate your efforts. This isn't actually working correctly though.  As i mentioned earlier, no cells in column A are completely blank. They all contain a formula. The blank cells are just those where the formula evaluates to null

Comment: Yes, helper columns are fine

Comment: No worries. I have just tried FALSE, and that had no effect.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010. If you look at my cell arrangement in my original question, with formulas in all the A cells, B1 contains "A1:A1", B4 contains "A4:A4" etc. If I physically delete the formulas from the empty cells in the A Column, the B column shows the correct values.

Comment: Thanks again pnuts. i really do appreciate you persisting with this.  We are one step closer, but ISFORMULA was introduced in Excel 2013. i am running Excel 2010. is there an equivalent?